# How to add an empty index in a list and increment it with vuejs and axios

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

I get data from a json array and I loop over it to display a form to update in database. I use v-for to display the information and I want to add or remove an index and see the rendering on my form

I create a method to add an index but the console returns me

```
0: {…}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
2: {__ob__: Observer}
3: {label: "", description: "", price: "", qtn: ""}
length: 4
```

Index 0 contains metadata (vendor name, date) and index 3 is the new, and he is not observable
How to do ?

Json example :

```
var v = {
    0: {
        'name': 'Alexis',
        'name_seller': 'Test',
        'price': 859,
        'tva': 20,
        'ect...': 'ect',
    },
    1: {
        'label': 'Site wordpress',
        'description': 'blablabla',
        'price': 400,
        'qtn': 2,
    },

    2: {
        'label': 'Extension wordpress',
        'description': 'blablabla',
        'price': 59,
        'qtn': 1,
    }
}
```

Html (i use laravel):

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="[[inc()]]" class="btn btn-alt btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Ajouter"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>


<input type="hidden" value="{{$type}}" id="type">
<input type="hidden" value="{{$box->id}}" id="boxId">

<!-- start block fields & boucle js -->
<div class="block" v-for="(value, i) in info" v-bind:key="i.id" v-if="i != 0" style="margin-bottom:45px;">

    <div class="block-title">
        <h2>Référence n°[[i]] </h2>
    </div>

    <!-- start fields -->
    <div class="form-horizontal form-bordered">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Libellé *</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" :name="'label'+[[i]]" :value="[[value.label]]">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Description</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <textarea rows="4" type="text" class="form-control" :name="'description'+[[i]]">[[value.description]]</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Prix *</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" :name="'price'+[[i]]" :value="[[value.price]]">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Quantité *</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" :name="'qtn'+[[i]]" :value="[[value.qtn]]">
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <!-- end fields -->

</div>
<!-- end boucle & block -->
```

Vuejs

```
var updatePdf = new Vue({
    el: '#updatePaper',
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data: {
        info: null,
        id: document.querySelector('#boxId').value,
        type: document.querySelector('#type').value,
    },
    methods: {
        inc() {
            this.info[this.info.length] =  {
                'label': '',
                'description': '',
                'price': '',
                'qtn': '',
            }
            console.log(this.info, this.info.length)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
            .get('/get/doc/' + this.type + '/' + this.id)
            .then(response => (this.info = response.data))
    },
});
```

if I click on .btn; I have the index but I think he isnt understood by vuejs, my intances aren't ordered
Can you help me ? 
Thank you in advance for your time and have a nice day

Comment: Updating an array by index won't work. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats. You can use `this.info.push` instead.

Comment: Thank you , it work with  `Vue.set(updatePdf.info, 3, 'test')` 
I went to see the documentation earlier, I found v-for combined v-if but I scrolled too fast.
Now I have to adapt it, thanks again :)